# Create strongly typed array of arrays in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In a language like C# I can declare a list of lists like:

```
List<List<int>> list_of_lists;
```

Is there a similar way to declare a strongly typed array of arrays in TypeScript?  I tried the following approaches but neither compiles.

```
var list_of_lists:int[][];
var list_of_lists:Array<int[]>;
```

Comment: Please don't use the term [*typed arrays*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) for this…

Comment: In TypeScript "typed array" means what it means in most every other programming language except JavaScript, but since they are closely tied together I'll clarify it with "strongly".

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the term "strongly typed" :-)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

`int` is not a type in TypeScript. You probably want to use `number`:

```
var listOfLists : number[][];
```

Comment: it's not strongly typed though

Comment: @PeterOlson is it possible to strongly type if I have array of arrays of such format - `[ [string, number], [string, number], ... ]` ?

Comment: for an array of array of different types `var entries: [string, number][] = []`

Comment: Is handled differently from the Array<Array<number>> syntax?

Answer (score 50):

You do it exactly like in Java/C#, e.g. (in a class):

```
class SomeClass {
    public someVariable: Array<Array<AnyTypeYouWant>>;
}
```

Or as a standalone variable:

```
var someOtherVariable: Array<Array<AnyTypeYouWant>>;
```

Comment: I actually used the any type in Angular, Array<Array<any>>

Answer (score 16):

The simplest is:

```
x: Array<Array<Any>>
```

And, if you need something more complex, you can do something like this:

```
y: Array<Array<{z:int, w:string, r:Time}>>
```

Answer (score 11):

@Eugene you can use something like `Array<Array<[string, number]>>` to define a Map type

Comment: This seems like it should be a response to that person's comment, instead of a separate answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own custom types to create a strongly typed array:

```
type GridRow = GridCell[]   //array of cells
const grid: GridRow[] = []; //array of rows
```

Answer (score 4):

It may look odd, but in TypeScript, you can create typed array of arrays, using the following syntax.

For example to create an array of numbers you could write the following:

```
const numbers: number[] = []; // or more verbose Array<number>
```

And to create an array of arrays of numbers, you could write the following:

```
const numbers: number[][] = []; // or more verbose Array<Array<number>>
```