# Tyescript: How to define typings for Strongly typed Array of Array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, strong-typing

There is already [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161486/create-strongly-typed-array-of-arrays-in-typescript), only difference is that I want to declare the typings in a `d.ts` file instead of declaring every time.

I have been writing typings like

```
interface SomeType {
 key1: string[];
 key2: number;
}
```

which are `Objects with named properties` type.

---

Now I need an `Array with two sub-Arrays` type,

**i.e** (something like):

```
 TheType : [string[], string[]]
```

---

So that I can write

```
let myVar: TheType;
```

instead of

```
let myVar: [string[], string[]];
```

---

**I've Tried** to play with `namespace`, `module`, `declare var` with no luck, I can explain the problems with them if required, but I just feel that either I'm missing something very obvious or it's just not possible ?!

**Note: workarounds !needed, thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would mix an interface extending `Array` with a generic to create a `NestedArray` type, which you can use with any type. Having a nested array type will make your inline types more readable:

```
interface NestedArray<T> extends Array<Array<T>> {}

var x: NestedArray<string> = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']];

var y = x[0]; // y is Array<string>
var z = x[0][1]; // z is string
```

Use with other types:

```
var x: NestadArray<Customer> = [];
```

Comment: `NestedArray` seems legit, nice