# How to specify type for a variable?

Tags: typescript

I am having a variable. It's an array of string arrays. How can I declare it with type.

```
let map = [ ['key1', 'value1'],['key2', 'value2']  ] ;
```

I mean for example if I have variable that holds a string I can declare it like this. In the following code I am making it clear that I am declaring a variable whose type is string.

```
let test:string = 'hello';
```

So similarly how I can I specify the type for the "map" variable in TypeScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create strongly typed array of arrays in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161486/create-strongly-typed-array-of-arrays-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for what it's worth, you don't have to declare the type of `map`. TypeScript will infer the type from the initializer.

But if you wanted to, it would either be

1. An array of arrays of strings: `string[][]` / `Array<Array<string>>`

```typescript
let map: string[][] = [ ['key1', 'value1'],['key2', 'value2']  ] ;
```

*(This is the type TypeScript will infer if you don't specify one.)*

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtghgDgLggZzAJwJYDsDmBtAXUIgF4I9yByAaxAE8BGSgGgkoDcZgBXEJg5nhr0ATCzaceIMQQgRZAbgBQQA)

or

2. An array of `string`,`string` [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple): `[string, string][]` / `Array<[string, string]>`

```typescript
let map: [string,string][] = [ ['key1', 'value1'],['key2', 'value2']  ] ;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtghgDgLggbQM5gE4EsB2BzAGnW3wF1lSIBeFFAcgGsQBPARjoIjoDcZgBXEO1IFkjFgCYOXXgJBTKESgG4AUEA)

[Tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple)...

> ...allow you to express an array with a fixed number of elements whose types are known, but need not be the same.