# What would be the type of a multidimensional array with an object in it?

Tags: typescript

A dummy question, but I can't figure it out.

I have a function that returns a multidimensional array with an object within it:

`[[{ shift: string }]]`

```
export const generateEmpty3dShiftsArray = (): RETURNTYPE??? => {
  const array = [[]];
  const months = 12;

  for (let month = 0; month < months; month++) {
    const monthDays = new Date(2021, month + 1, 0).getDate();
    array[0].push([]);

    for (let day = 0; day < monthDays; day++) {
      array[0][month].push({ shift: "X" });
    }
  }

  return array;
};
```

So I can not figure out what is the actual return type of the function, `[[{ shift: string }]]` does not work.

And I am guessing that I have to use the exact same type when declaring `const array = [[]]`;

Because lint complains more within the code itself at both `push` functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create strongly typed array of arrays in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161486/create-strongly-typed-array-of-arrays-in-typescript)

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes the Array<Array<Array<{ shift: string}>>> worked, but Charlie's way is shorter

Comment: "Charlie's way", using `Type[]` instead of `Array<Type>` is _also_ covered on the duplicate; that's the _accepted_ answer, in fact.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, it was number[][] and I it wasnt apparent to me that I can replace number with { shift: string }, so I just glanced over it when I was looking at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data is something like this:

```
[[{'foo':'some foo'}], []]
```

the type should be:

```
{[key:string]:string}[][]
```

This reads something like - an array of array of objects whose values are all strings

Comment: Thanks, using { shift: string }[][][] worked.